# How do I change the settings for the ENBSeries graphical mod for Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues, mods

I've finally got it installed with ATT and my AMD Mobility Radeon 3650, but the image is very blurry and the colors aren't as vibrant.

How do I change this? My screen resolution is 1024x600. I'm using the default .ini file.

Comment: @Downvote: Why close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've compared 3 presets: Gionight, Confident and Nightwalker. The best is from Gionight. It has the best colors and it runs good on low quality settings. Here is a Download-Link: http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=5516. The one from Confident is pratically the same like the default preset and very blurry and weak colors and the one from Nightwalker is too dark or the colors is too extreme and it's not very balanced.